# Correct abbreviation of "engineer"

Tags: abbreviations

What is the correct abbreviation of *engineer*? In my organization, some of my colleagues use *Eng.* and some use *Engr.*

Comment: Note that "Engineer" is not used as a title in Britain or (as far as I know) other English-speaking countries. This is in contrast with much of Europe.

Comment: 'Eng.' looks a lot like an abbreviation for 'English' which is very different from 'Engineering'.

Comment: I can’t think of a situation when you would want to use an abbreviation for engineering.

Comment: Different situations like use as an honorific, in some text where I don't want to use the whole word

Comment: @ColinFine: *Engineer* on its own isn't used in Britain; but *Chartered Engineer* (CEng) is, and there's an equivalent European qualification -- also awarded by the UK Engineering Council -- of IngEur as well. No-one's mentioned *Ing*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: _CEng_ is letters after the name, and it is specifically "CEng". Ditto "B.Eng". They are not titles like _Dr_.

Comment: @tchrist As a technical writer doing a lot of block/flow diagrams I need to use abbreviations all the time. At the moment I'm working on a flow diagram having to do with requesting approval to establish a new device in the company's parts database. One of the steps in the approval process is review by our Component Engineer. To make the text fit in a reasonably sized block without the font being too small to easily read, I want to abbreviate the word "Engineer," which is what brought me to this page. I am sure there are plenty of other good reasons for wanting to abbreviate it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no common standard abbreviation for *engineer*, so generally it would be best to pick one and be consistent.

*Eng.* is sometimes an abbreviation for *engineering* in degrees such as B.Eng., [Bachelor of Engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Engineering). Therefore, it might be better to use *Engr.* if it's important to fully disambiguate between the two.

Comment: Differentiate between which two what? A Bachelor of English?

Comment: I meant if you use Eng. it might not be clear if you mean *engineering* or *engineer*, so Engr. may be less ambiguous.

Comment: Oh. I don't think that would confuse anybody or is a significant difference.

Comment: Yeah, so just pick one and be consistent.

Comment: Pick the shortened form or what the shortened form stands for? if the latter, why bother, since you can't see it?

Comment: If you must abbreviate it, pick Eng. or Engr., your choice, but then use it consistently.

Answer (score 9):

There is no internationally accepted standard. Different countries use different abbreviations. This [link lists some of the local forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk_archive/Humanities/2006_October_2#Short_form_for_engineers) used in different countries. Some of the common ones are:

**Engineer:**

> *Eng.* (**most common**)
>
> *Engr.*
>
> *Er.*

**Engineering:**

> *Engg.* (**most common**)
>
> *Eng.*

Answer (score 6):

I don't think I've ever seen any abbreviation of "engineer" by itself as an honorific abbreviation after a person's name, but I've seen plenty of other honorific abbreviations after people's names that include an "E" for engineer:

PE "professional engineer": a person with a state-issued PE license. In the United States and Canada, it's generally illegal to build certain things for use by the public, unless the plans have been signed by a PE (roads, bridges, dams, tall buildings, electric substations, etc.). Typically a person gets a PE license from the state after both 4 years of academic training and also 4 more years of practical experience working under some other PE. I hear that CEng and Eur Ing are the equivalents in other countries. This is analogous to LPN "licensed practical nurse".

CE, ME, EE, IE, ChE, EIT, etc.: A person who has graduated with a university degree in the indicated field of engineering, but may or may not have any practical experience. This is analogous to MSN "Master of Science in Nursing".

MCSE (which has since been renamed MCITP to avoid the controversy mentioned below), SE, NE (network engineer), DE (design engineer), TE, etc.: A person who has some experience applying scientific or mathematical knowledge to technical problems ("engineering"), and has either passed some test related to it, or does these things as part of his day-to-day job (and perhaps that abbreviation is an abbreviation of his job title), but does not necessarily have any academic training.
This is analogous to people who have had one-day training in doing CPR and AED, and have plenty of experience "nursing someone back to health with chicken soup", but may not have any other academic training.

IEEE, ASME, IETF, SAE, etc.: a person who is a member of the specified engineering organization. Often many members are college students who hope someday to get a degree in engineering, but have no academic qualifications or practical experience. Sometimes these organizations publish standards that are more influential than any single PE.

There's a pretty big [controversy over the word "engineer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_over_the_term_Engineer) -- should people who are not PEs should be allowed to call themselves "engineers"?
I think this is analogous to the confusion some people have over "doctors" who have no medical training, but have a doctorate degree in some non-medical field.

Answer (score 3):

The NOAD lists both *eng*. and *engr*. as valid abbreviations.

Not that the NOAD is an ultimate authority, but I found it interesting that *eng*. could be used to abbreviate both *engineer* and *engineering*, yet *engr*. lists *engineer* but **not** *engineering*:

> **eng.**
>   *abbreviation*
>   • engine.
>   • engineer.
>   • engineering.
>   • engraved.
>   • engraver.
>   • engraving.
>
> **engr**.
>   *abbreviation*
>   • engineer.
>   • engraved.
>   • engraver.
>   • engraving.

Comment: You missed **engrained, engrossed, etc.**

Comment: I was just going off of what NOAD listed.

Answer (score 0):

*Eng.* may be ambiguous and appear to be an abbreviation for English. The best abbreviation for engineer that I have seen is *Engr.*.

Answer (score -3):

*Er.*, the shortest the best. Better to *eng.* or *engr.*